# Importar un certificado firmado por una CA a un dispositivo criptografico

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda para importar un certificado firmado por una CA a un dispositivo criptografico

Estoy usando pytho con las librerias pkcs11

```
from pkcs11 import KeyType, Attribute, ObjectClass, lib, Slot
from pkcs11.util.rsa import decode_rsa_private_key, encode_rsa_public_key
# from Crypto.PrivateKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
import argparse
from pkcs11.util.x509 import decode_x509_certificate

with token.open(user_pin=pin, rw=True) as session:
    if params==1:
        generateKeyPair()
    if params == 2:    
        cert = session.create_object(decode_x509_certificate("""p½ur Ê^ÞËm?×Å´9òã­qp±Ë.WAVCå§õß–y¾³Û™.su/0È™™’ÏBE¶r+Nð âÆÔù4©5íGgÂ™\gÉcÔ‰p......"""))
```

Me tira este error. No estoy seguro de si esta seria la forma correcta de subir un certificado.Probe importarlo en formato DER Y CER pero recibo el mismo error.

```
  x509 = Certificate.load(der)
File "C:\Users\digit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\asn1crypto\core.py", line 224, in load
  raise TypeError('encoded_data must be a byte string, not %s' % type_name(encoded_data))
TypeError: encoded_data must be a byte string, not str
```

Comment: el error te dice que le estas pasando un string a una función que necesita recibir bytes. Lo puedes solucionar llamando al método `.enccode()` de los strings o anteponiendo una `b` al inicializar un string, por ejemplo `b"un sting"`

Comment: Corrigiendo esa parte me tira este mensaje ```
    raise ValueError(_INSUFFICIENT_DATA_MESSAGE % (contents_end, data_len))
ValueError: Insufficient data - 6345336507634983572889978492857593484077478311232161866864025474572049480688502975603360896385 bytes requested 
but only 237 available ```

Comment: hasta aquí llego, no sé nada del módulo que usas ni de lo que haces, lo siento no poder ayudar más >_<